# get post id in while loops outputting page id

Tags: posts, advanced-custom-fields, id

it's been a while since I used wordpress and I am trying to us e advanced custom fields, I am trying to output the post ID inside a loop on a page, so i can use get_field to output the post contents. Ths $post->ID gives me the page id not the post id so thr wrong number is being outputted, how do I get the post ID?

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php $current_id = $post->ID ?>

   <?php echo $current_id ?>

            <h1><?php the_field('titleFart', $current_id); ?></h1>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: how are you querying for posts in the page?

Comment: If you echo get_the_id(), are the numbers the same?

Comment: yes they are both the page id not the post id

Comment: @Milo oh may not be doing that oops

Comment: All I need was this query_posts( 'posts_per_page=5' ); been a long time since ive touched wordpress all javascript now thanks

Answer (score 4):

Dont use `query_posts` or `WP_Query` if you need it in the main loop. Dont ever use `query_posts` anyway.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

   <?php $current_id = get_the_ID(); ?>
   <?php echo $current_id ?>

            <h1><?php the_field('titleFart', $current_id); ?></h1>

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Because: [`get_the_ID()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/get_the_id)

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

> > **Note:** This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter
> >     the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way
> >     to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of
> >     the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright
> >     fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts
> >     pagination). Any modern WP code should use more reliable methods, like
> >     making use of pre_get_posts hook, for this purpose.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

In your case, you are creating a secondary loop on a page so what you want is a new [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) object.

```
$q = new WP_Query(
  array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5
  )
);

if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    $q->the_post(); 
    $current_id = $post->ID;
    echo $current_id ?>
      <h1><?php the_field('titleFart', $current_id); ?></h1><?php 
  } // end of the loop. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use wp_query() with your params instead. Query_posts slows down your queries.   http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query